# Error CS0103 The name 'db' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm assuming I'm missing a namespace declared on the top of my controller but I tried with 'using WebMatrix.Data;' and 'using System.IO;' that they are the usual suggestions for this error. It didn't work.

I'm trying to display more than one database table in the same view and this error is stopping me. Help please.

My Controller:

```
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web.Mvc; 
using KMS.Models; 
using WebMatrix.Data; 
using System.IO;


namespace KMS.Controllers
 {

public class KMSController : Controller{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        KMSConection cs = new KMSConection();
        cs.Areas = (from o in db.Areas select o).Tolist();
        cs.AreaTypes = (from o in db.AreaTypes select or).Tolist();
        return View(cs);
    }
  }
}
```

My ViewModel Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using KMS.Models;

 namespace KMS.Models
 {
  public class KMSConection: ApplicationDbContext
  {
    public DbSet<Area> Areas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AreaType> AreaTypes { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `db` sounds like a variable/field that you never declared, not a missing `using` statement. I would suggest you to read your code line by line

Comment: you are not opening a dataset/database to read from which I assume `db` is. You have a connection - open something on it?

Comment: Found it! I was missing the line: private KMSSampleEntities1 db = new KMSSampleEntities1(); on the top of my Index view. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not mentioning the db variable you have created into your KMSController. Try this code to fix the error:

```
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web.Mvc; 
using KMS.Models; 
using WebMatrix.Data; 
using System.IO;


namespace KMS.Controllers
 {

public class KMSController : Controller{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Insert the actual entity referred to your db variable. 
        //Probably something like:
        //var db = Some Database Context

        KMSConection cs = new KMSConection();
        cs.Areas = (from o in db.Areas select o).Tolist();
        cs.AreaTypes = (from o in db.AreaTypes select or).Tolist();
        return View(cs);
    }
  }
}
```